# How to create this in html canvas, handling free flowing text with variable heights

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

[image]

I need to create this in HTML Canvas,from what research i have done I have struggled to find any useful cases examples of it (most are just experiments demonstrating immense visuals). 
I've seen this project for react js [react-canvas](https://github.com/Flipboard/react-canvas). And interesting
[blog post](http://engineering.flipboard.com/2015/02/mobile-web/).

I would not be using react i would be wanting to do this standalone in canvas (using any canvas libraries when needed)

Answer (score 1):

There's a function you can use that checks the length of a piece of text:

```
ctx.measureText(string).width;
```

You can incrementally add words to a row until it becomes too long, then you post it and move down one row and repeat.

Sloppy fiddle to show you the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/1kqyxdd2/

**EDIT:** the fiddle above cuts the last word in each sentance. I've re-made it here: http://jsfiddle.net/1kqyxdd2/1/

```js
c = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var text = "Here's a long text that I'd like to wrap into a certain width. I really hope that my function will be able to handle this, YIKES!";

function writeText(wrapWidth,textString,x,y,fontSize,fontFamily) {
    var words = textString.split(" ");
    var tempText="";
    var currentY=y;
    ctx.font= fontSize+"pt "+fontFamily
    for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
        if (ctx.measureText(tempText+" "+words[i]).width>wrapWidth) {
            ctx.fillText(tempText,x,currentY);
            currentY+=fontSize+4; //the 4 is line spacing
            tempText="";
            i--;
        }
        else {
            tempText+=" "+words[i];
        }
    }
    ctx.fillText(tempText,x,currentY);
}
writeText(200,text,50,20,15,"Arial");
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Upvote. Good answer. You might also return the `currentY` value from `writeText` so you know where the current paragraph stopped drawing. This would be important for vertical positioning if you want to string multiple paragraphs together.

Comment: @markE, thanks. I had limited time before I had to leave the comp so it became sloppy. Ideally I'd also add the x- and y-coordinates (perhaps also font information) as parameters to the function.